# Create a similar table from one DB on another DB using python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

Im new to python. here is my problem
I have two Oracle data bases in two different locations (target and source). one in IP1 (target) and other in IP2(source)
What I need to do is make a copy of a table in IP2 in to IP1. Similar to CREATE TABLE...AS

I tried creating two cursors like below

```
curTarget = db_con_target.cursor() -->IP1
curSource = db_con_source.cursor() -->IP2

curTarget.execute("""create table TargetTable as (""",curSource.execute("select * from SourceTable"))
```

it seems I can not provide an output of a cursor execution to execute another cursor.
Is there a way to do this ? can any expert shed some light on this.

Comment: Why not just use CREATE TABLE AS.. select * from .. ? Create a dblink to IP2 to IP1.  No coding required.

Comment: what I need to do is migrate a set of tables IP2 to IP1. this is invoked by a different process. also I need to change the tables which need to migrate dynamically. that's why I'm using the python script. I don't think creating a DB link would work

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to provide the output of a cursor to another cursor.
so what I did is manipulate the output of the cursor and create the CREATE TABLE query manually. 
It worked.
for ex :
    curSource = db_con_source.cursor()

```
    describeQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName.strip() + " WHERE 1=0"
    createTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName.strip() + " ("

    #print describeQuery    
    curSource.execute(describeQuery)

    for desc in curSource.description:
            print desc
            column_name = desc[0]

            if desc[6]== 0 :
                    nullable = "NOT NULL"
            else :
                    nullable = "NULL"

            if desc[1].__name__ == "STRING" :
                    data_type = "VARCHAR2"
                    data_length = desc[3]

                    #creating the query here for string types since it does not involve the precision
                    createTableQuery = createTableQuery + " " + column_name + " " + data_type + "(" + str(data_length) + ") " + nullable + ", "
            elif desc[1].__name__ == "NATIVE_FLOAT" :
                    data_type = "BINARY_DOUBLE"
                    createTableQuery = createTableQuery + " " + column_name + " " + data_type + " " +  nullable + ", "
            else :
                    data_type = "NUMBER"
                    data_length = desc[4]
                    precision = desc[5]

                    if data_length == 0:
                            createTableQuery = createTableQuery + " " + column_name + " " + data_type + " " +  nullable + ", "
                    else:
                            #creating the query here for int types since it does invole both length and the precision
                            createTableQuery = createTableQuery + " " + column_name + " " + data_type + "(" + str(data_length) + "," + str(precision) + ") " + nullable + ", "

    #remove last two characters : space and comma 
    createTableQuery = createTableQuery[:-2]
    createTableQuery = createTableQuery + " )"
```